# Change objects in array in Observable<MyClass[]> not the array itself with rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I get an Observable of an array of objects (`Observable<MyClass[]>`) so when I `tap` the observable i see an array not the elements themselfs. I want to change the objects in the array not the array itself and I have a hard time doing that.
the actual class is something like

```
{date: Date, activity: boolean, activityId?:string, first?: boolean, last?: boolean, ...}

const array$: Observable<MyClass[]> = of([{date: new Date(), activity: true},{date: new Date(), 
      activity: false},{date: new Date(), activity: false}]).pipe(tap(console.log));
```

When activity is false on a day and the previous isn't the first boolean should be set to true etc, but when I'm having a hard time not introducing side effects.

inside the `pipe()` I tried to do `concatMap` and then `toArray()` in the end but when I tap before the `toArray` I see each element and can change them but the actual output after `toArray` is not like the original value I put through to my html so it shows nothing. Same as what was answered down below.

Made a stackblitz of a simplified version of what I got.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvbvhx?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in the question*. Also I wouldn't recommend using a tap for side effects, that's not the right semantics.

Comment: Meant with the tap what I console logged.

Comment: Oh, I see; yes, that's what I'd expect from an observable of arrays. It's still unclear what a "hard time" might be and the example is off-site.

Comment: I want to change items in the array but still show the array in my html and once I start to map I lose parts I want to show. I know I'm vague that's why I made a stackblitz, I'm bad at explaining it. :)

Comment: But, again, *that's off-site*. The MRE needs to be *in the question* (you can include a stackblitz link *in addition*).

Comment: Oh you mean paste part of it here. Alright I'm on it.

Comment: That's **not** a [mcve]. It shows absolutely no attempt to implement the behaviour you describe, nor does it illustrate the problem you had when you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Array.map` within an RxJS `map`:

```js
const modified$ = original$.pipe(
  map(array => array.map(element => modifyElement()))
);
```

You can also do it purely with RxJS operators, but you then need to choose the specific behaviour you want. One option:

```js
const modified$ = original$.pipe(
  concatMap(array => from(array)),
  map(element => modifyElement()),
  toArray()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` method also take `index` and the `array` as it's parameters which then you can archive it like this:

```
  schedule$ = of(this.createSchedule()).pipe(map( arr => arr.map((date, i, arr) => {
       //when activity is false and the previous wasn't set the first boolean true
       if( date.activity == false && i > 0 && arr[i - 1].activity == false  ) {
         arr[i - 1].activity = true;
       }
       //when activity is false and the next isn't set the last boolean true
       if( date.activity == false && arr[i + 1].activity == false ) {
         arr[i + 1].activity = true;
       }
       return date
  })), tap(console.log))
```

Comment: With first and last I was referring to the booleans first and last of the schedule model not the activity boolean but I'll give it a try.